# glsl dynamic light count via uniforms

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

I have a problem with my webgl2 glsl shader code. I **dont** use three.js or babylon.js, i am using the webgl2 js api directly. I want to have a dynamic count of lights in my scene, and it does not work always and / or behaves weird.

When i did a google search, i found some discussions and informations, saying that you cannot have a dynamic count of lights via a uniform due to hardware limitations and loop unrolling on the gpu. Some people say that you should not have loops in your shader code with dynamic branching in it.

I observed some really strange behaviour, where a float uniform (casted to an int) seems to be fine as a loop expression, and a int uniform is not. If i try to use a int uniform in a loop expression, the page freezes for a moment and i loose the webgl2 context. If i do a break or a if in the for loop, it does not loose the context, but it again only works for float values which where casted to an int.

Code (also visible in screenshots):

```
struct PointLight {
    vec3 color;
    vec3 position;
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

// fine
layout(std140) uniform LightUniforms {
    DirectionalLight dirLights[2];
    PointLight pointLights[2];
    float pointLightsCount; // <== here
};

// not fine
layout(std140) uniform LightUniforms {
    DirectionalLight dirLights[2];
    PointLight pointLights[2];
    int pointLightsCount; // <== here
};
```

My questions are:

- What are the best practices for arrays with dynamic length in glsl?
- Should i be concerned with `ifs` or `breaks` in loops. Is this bad practice or results in bad performance, because the gpu unrolls loops?
- Can i safely go with a float uniform that gets casted to an int, or will this produce errors on different hardware?

With `floats` (casted to an `int`) it works:
[image: Works]

With an `int` uniform it does not work:
[image: Does not work]

I can even use the `float` uniform inside of an loop expression without problems, but using a `int` would result in a context lost error:
[image: loop expression]

Help please!

Comment: How are you constructing and setting the uniform data? I suspect that you might submit misaligned data in the case where your uniform block has mixed types in it, querying and inspecting the layout might cast some light onto this.